# Прозрачная, прокликиваемая "внутрь" форма

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать форму прокликиваемой? На форме label с фоновым изображением, нужно чтобы при клике на форму и label, клик уходил в окно за ней...

Comment: Знает кто как сделать? Чтобы вся форма была прокликиваемая и клик уходил в окно за формой)

Comment: Самое простое, что приходит в голову это на BG форме создать паблик метод получения координат клика и соответствующих действий на этой форме(вычисление по координатам где был клик https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272681/how-can-i-simulate-a-mouse-click-at-a-certain-position-on-the-screen). в форму с лейблом передать в качестве напр. парента BG форму и вызывать метод BG формы передавая координаты кликов в метод получения координат.

Comment: Посложнее можно с делегатами...

Comment: спасибо большое, постараюсь что-нибудь придумать... если есть у кого-то еще варианты, обязательно пишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо просто установить специальные атрибуты окна, по такому же принципу многие разработчики делают ScreenSaver'ы. `SetWindowLong/GetWindowLong` с установкой бита `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` в стиле окна, что делает наше окно "прокликиваемым".

Задаем нашему окну `AllowsTransparency="True"`, стиль `WindowStyle="None"` и делаем его поыерх всех `Topmost="True"`.

> AllowsTransparency существует для упрощения создания непрямоугольных
>   окон и, следовательно, если AllowsTransparency имеет значение true,
>   окна WindowStyle свойство должно быть присвоено None.

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;


namespace UnClickable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            WindowProperties.SetWindowExTransparent(hwnd);
        }
    }
}
```

***WindowProperties.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UnClickable
{
    public static class WindowProperties
    {
        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
        const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

        // This static method is required because Win32 does not support
        // SetWindowLongPtr directly
        public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
        {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
            else
                return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong.ToInt32()));
        }

        // This static method is required because Win32 does not support
        // GetWindowLongPtr directly
        public static IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex)
        {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                return GetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex);
            else
                return GetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, int index, int newStyle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int index, IntPtr newStyle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongPtr")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        public static void SetWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            var extendedStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, new IntPtr(extendedStyle.ToInt32() | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));
        }
    }
}
```

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
<Window x:Class="UnClickable.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UnClickable"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Topmost="True">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, ты топовый чувак!